# learning open cv can someone decipher a section of code for me?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

As I said im learning to use OpenCV with my robotics team and my programming lead gave our sub-sub-group some vision code to explore and play with. there is a section of code which I know is relevant to what I'm trying to do. (I'm replacing the 6 sliders he had with a color palette and accuracy adjust) But i dont know what this section of code is doing.

```
def getVars():
    bars = ("LowH", "LowS", "LowV", "HighH", "HighS", "HighV")
    out = []
    for bar in bars:
        out.append(cv2.getTrackbarPos(bar, "Control"))
    return out
```

I know the High and lows are the same as the names used for the sliders in the trackbar section but they are just strings in what I understand is a tuple. I don't know what the out.append line does. 
Here is the rest of the code for context, there are some unused parts that i have added but not yet implemented.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkColorChooser import askcolor  
import colorsys    
import cv2
import numpy

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

lowH = 1
highH = 179
lowS = 1
highS = 255
lowV = 1
highV = 255

def callback(x): pass
def getColor():
    color = askcolor() 
    #Lines above this initiate the color wheel
    #Below lines extract the output and convert to HSV
    ((red, green, blue), hexcode ) = color 
    rfloat = float(red)
    gfloat = float(green)
    bfloat = float(blue)
    r, g, b = rfloat/255, gfloat/255, bfloat/255
    print (red, green, blue), "RGB"
    print (r, g, b), "RGB 0-1"
    h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
    print (h, s, v), "HSV"
    hsv = (h, s, v)
    return hsv


def getVars():
    bars = ("LowH", "LowS", "LowV", "HighH", "HighS", "HighV")
    out = []
    for bar in bars:
        out.append(cv2.getTrackbarPos(bar, "Control"))
    return out
Button(text='Select Color', command=getColor).pack()
print getVars()
cv2.namedWindow("Control")
cv2.createTrackbar("LowH", "Control", 0, 179, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar("HighH", "Control", 0, 179, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar("LowS", "Control", 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar("HighS", "Control", 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar("LowV", "Control", 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar("HighV", "Control", 0, 255, callback)

while True:
    values = getVars()
    #print(values, values[:3], values[3:])
    (cap, frame) = camera.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #threshold = hsv
    threshold = cv2.inRange(hsv, tuple(values[:3]), tuple(values[3:]))
    #contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, 1, 2)
    #cnt = contours[0]
    #M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    #cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'] if M["m00"] != 0 else 0)
    #cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'] if M["m00"] != 0 else 0)
    #cv2.circle(threshold, (cx,cy), 3, (0,250,0), -1)
    cv2.imshow("Output", threshold)
    cv2.imshow("Original", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`out.append(cv2.getTrackbarPos(bar, "Control"))`

simply populates an array with the current trackbarvalues
--> first the three lower limits for the HSV colorspace, and then the three upper limits

These 6 values are then used for cv2.inRange(src, lowerb, upperb)

tuple(values[:3]) gets the first 3 elements (=lower limits)
tuple(values[3:]) gets the last 3 elements (=upper limits)

These are not strings, but int values returned from

```
cv2.getTrackbarPos(bar, "Control")
```

The strings were only used to reference the different controls by their name as defined in

```
cv2.createTrackbar("LowH", "Control", 0, 179, callback)
```

The inRange returns 255 if all 3 values of hsv are within the limits defined in the 3 element tuples extracted from the values array

```
cv2.inRange(hsv, tuple(values[:3]), tuple(values[3:]))
```

[opencv Docs/ Array Operations]